# Getting a CMake Error trying to create a catkin workspace in ROS, because it could not find the PythonInterp

Tags: python, ros, catkin

I am getting a CMake Error while trying to create a catkin workspace in ROS, because it could not find the PythonInterp. It found an unsuitable version "1.4", but it required to at least have 2. However, I have already downloaded python at a higher version for ros.

This is what I get when I run catkin_make

```
nasa@nasa-VirtualBox:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/nasa/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/nasa/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/nasa/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/nasa/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/nasa/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/nasa/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/nasa/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/melodic
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/melodic
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version "1.4", but required
  is at least "2" (found /home/nasa/catkin_ws/build/python3)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:376 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPythonInterp.cmake:152 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/python.cmake:4 (find_package)
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:163 (include)
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:56 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/nasa/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/nasa/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:320: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the command `$python -V` to check the version of python.

If version is 2.7, then:

1. go to catkin_ws
2. delete folder devel and build again
3. Open another terminal, in the workspace and try again.

Answer (score 0):

The solution might be to clean your workspace. As hinted here [the first link in google after searching for the error](https://github.com/YosysHQ/nextpnr/issues/214), where the problem was CMakeCache.txt. Depending on whether you use `catkin build` or `catkin_make` you can either run `catkin clean` or `catkin_make clean` in your catkin workspace. Just deleting the devel and build folders in the workspace should also work for either of the build systems.

You might also get faster answers to ROS releated questions on https://answers.ros.org/questions/

If cleaning the workspace does not solve the problem then check the version of python reported from the terminal `python --version`. Also if you installed the new version of python and from the same terminal tried to build the workspace then the relevant ENVIRONMENT paths might not have been updated in that shell. Either run `exec bash` or start a new terminal and try building your workspace.